# How to apply fillters like blur to an element in React-Konva

Tags: filter, konvajs

I've been trying to get a blurred circle by using:

```
var circle = <Circle
    width={200}
    fill={'#ff55ff'}
    x={100}
    y={100}
  />;

circle .cahce();
circle .filters([Konva.Filters.Blur]);
circle .blurRadius(10);
```

But  get this error:

> rect.cahce is not a function

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using React:**

This code will create "react element":

```
var circle = <Circle
  width={200}
  fill={'#ff55ff'}
  x={100}
  y={100}
/>;
```

You can read more about "react component" vs "react element" if you will to.

But `shape.cache()`, `shape.filters([])` are methods of `Konva` nodes. If you want to access `Konva` nodes you need to access it with component reference:

```
class MyRect extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.rect.cache();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Rect
        filters={[Konva.Filters.Noise]}
        noise={1}
        x={10}
        y={10}
        width={50}
        height={50}
        fill="red"
        shadowBlur={10}
        ref={node => {
          this.rect = node;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

You can see a demo here: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/react/Filters.html

**Without react:**

You can create circle node instance with this:

```
var circle = new Konva.Circle({
    radius: 200,
    fill: '#ff55ff',
    x: 100,
    y: 100
});
```

Then you can use all its methods:

```
circle.cache();    // not "cahce"
circle.filters([Konva.Filters.Blur]);
circle.blurRadius(10);
```